# Сборка строки с кавычками на Golang

Tags: строки, golang, символы

Мне нужно собрать на golang строку типа:

```
copy "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx" "C:\yyy\yyy\yyy"
```

Из этого:

```
path1 := "C:\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx"
path2 := "C:\\yyy\\yyy\\yyy"
```

Для экранирования кавычек пробовал использовать **``**, но из-за этого в строке появляются какие-то дополнительные слеши.
Есть какой-нибудь способ собрать такую строку более менее легко?

Answer (score 0):

> Для экранирования кавычек пробовал использовать ``, но из-за этого
> в строке появляются какие-то дополнительные слеши.

Не «появляются», а вы сами их добавляете.  Обратные кавычки являются
верным методом:

```golang
path1 := `C:\xxx\xxx\xxx`
path2 := `C:\yyy\yyy\yyy`
```

С двойными кавычками внутри:

```golang
path1 := `"C:\xxx\xxx\xxx"`
path2 := `"C:\yyy\yyy\yyy"`
```

Ну и да, `os/exec` это всё не нужно, если вам для этого.